# Image Reader as Camera 2 preview

Tags: android, android-camera2

I got a little problem with having multiple preview output surfaces.
I got 2 surfaces, GLSurfaceView and an ImageReader.
What I tried so far;

- remove the ImageReader as preview target [works great]
- remove the GLSurfaceView leaving the imageReader alone [doesnt work]
- putting the 2 together as preview target. [doesnt work]

last 2 things have the same issue, the imageReader receive image, but only 7 frames, after that an error is thrown in the setRepeating CaptureCallback which has a failure reason REASON_ERROR.

I am sure they both share the same size 1024 x 768

Comment: Im not sure why 1 voted down, may be you can comment why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im still not sure why but after acquiring the image by calling `acquireNextImage()`, the error was gone. By the way, you need to close the acquire image.